# Detecting taps on UITableView background

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

What is the cleanest way to detect taps on a UITableView background? I'd like to catch these to dismiss the keyboard.

Unfortunately, when I add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the tableview, tapping the cells fires the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UI(Table)ViewController or in your UITableView, override

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

and if the keyboard is being shown, dismiss it. Also, don't forget to forward this event to your subviews.

Comment: Doesn't this also catch taps to the cells? I don't want that.

Comment: Then if the touch is in bounds of a UITableViewCell, don't forward your event down to subviews and simply dismiss the keyboard :)

Comment: Well, I guess I could grab the rects of all the cells and look for the touch - but was hoping for something at a bit higher level.

Answer (score 1):

Add the gesture in tableview's background view. Like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                             action:@selector(tableViewBackgroundTap)];

[self.tableView.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: Does not work without creating & setting the `backgroundView` first.